# how to achieve lookbehind regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
<p>text1</p>
<p>text2 <span class="theClass">text3</span></p>
```

What I need to achieve is to split this string into an array containing html tags and pure text. something like:

```
var array= ["<p>", "text1", "</p>", ...];
```

I've tried to use regexp: `/(?=<)|(?<=>)/g`, but javascript does not allow me to use lookbehind expression. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `html.match(/<.+?>|[^<]+/g)`

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
const data = `<p>text1</p>
<p>text2 <span class="theClass">text3</span></p>`

const split = data => data.split(/(<.*?>)/g).filter(x => x.trim())

console.log(split(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the solution. filtering through ES6 didn't cross my mind. Definitely clever and simple solution.

Comment: I'm happy to hear so :)